# How to install SSL certificate in Vapor web framework?

Tags: ssl, openssl, vapor

I want to install SSL(Comodo wildcard certificate, ex: "*.test.com")
in Vapor Web framework, the "servers.json" I got is:

```
{
    "default": {
        "port": "$PORT:443",
        "host": "api.test.com",
        "securityLayer": "tls",
        "tls": {
            "certificates": "chain",
            "certificateFile": "/path/ssl-bundle.crt",
            "chainFile": "/path/ssl-bundle.crt",
            "privateKeyFile": "/path/key.pem",
            "signature": "signedFile",
            "caCertificateFile": "/path/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt"
            }
    }
}
```

I already make sure that "public/private" key matches already using openssl command. And about the certificateFile part like "ssl-bundle.crt", I also tried "*.test.com.crt" with the "key.pem" as well(still pass the validation using openssl, the only difference is one is test.com's certificate, the other is bundle certificate, combined by correct orders already.). Besides, all certs and key's format are correct as well. And I also make sure the cert/key files location is correct so that the Vapor can find these files. But I still can't launch the server correctly, and always display the error.

I try to locate the exact location in xcode, but I can only see it fails in this method: "tls_accept_fds()", which is in tls_server.c of CLibreSSL library.

[image]

Also, I saw the error message the xcode displayed to me:

[image]

After use debug mode to trace, I can only know that it seems the program throws the error in "SSL_set_rfd()" or "SSL_set_rfd()", but I don't know exactly. The xcode only shows this to me, and I can't find any other error messages in the debug console. As result, so far I can only make sure that the error should be in this block:

```
int
tls_accept_fds(struct tls *ctx, struct tls **cctx, int fd_read, int fd_write)
{
struct tls *conn_ctx = NULL;

// I pass this block
if ((ctx->flags & TLS_SERVER) == 0) {
    tls_set_errorx(ctx, "not a server context");
    goto err;
}

// I pass this block
if ((conn_ctx = tls_server_conn(ctx)) == NULL) {
    tls_set_errorx(ctx, "connection context failure");
    goto err;
}

// I pass this block
if ((conn_ctx->ssl_conn = SSL_new(ctx->ssl_ctx)) == NULL) {
    tls_set_errorx(ctx, "ssl failure");
    goto err;
}

// I pass this block
if (SSL_set_app_data(conn_ctx->ssl_conn, conn_ctx) != 1) {
    tls_set_errorx(ctx, "ssl application data failure");
    goto err;
}

// The error occurs here, in SSL_set_rfd or SSL_set_wfd, it will then go to err part: "*cctx = NULL;", not even go into the if block.
if (SSL_set_rfd(conn_ctx->ssl_conn, fd_read) != 1 ||
    SSL_set_wfd(conn_ctx->ssl_conn, fd_write) != 1) {
    tls_set_errorx(ctx, "ssl file descriptor failure");
    goto err;
}

*cctx = conn_ctx;

return (0);

err:
tls_free(conn_ctx);

*cctx = NULL;

return (-1);
}
```

So, the above is all the info I got right now, and I can't find the solution on the internet for several days already...
Could anyone give me any hint about how to install SSL in Vapor web framework? I can correctly install the SSL in Apache, Nginx, Tomcat, etc already. But never success in Vapor, it seems like C library issue, but I don't know the real reason why it fails, thank you very much for any possible help.

Comment: Please remove the big pictures and add the relevant text. Text on the pictures and cannot be indexed. I don't speak for others, but I don't want to take the time to try and understand a bunch of pictures. Also, clearly state what the error is. I don't see it in your pictures.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your suggestions, I've removed the big pictures and add more info I got, I try to describe more about the error I got, though I can't figure out what's the real error occurred in this issue. Hope the updated description helps.

Comment: If you could create a failing test case on Vapor's TLS package: https://github.com/vapor/tls that would help us fix this the fastest. Either it's a bug in LibreSSL (possible but unlikely), an issue with your certificates (unlikely if they work with Nginx), or Vapor's TLS package is missing a function call to LibreSSL or calling one of the functions incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug has been found and fixed here: https://github.com/vapor/tls/pull/27